# Transform for BelongsTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I was wondering if it is possible to create a transform for belongsTo (and by extend hasMany) as my REST server returns relationships that are defined like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  lastname: DS.attr('string'),
  firstname: DS.attr('string'),
  company: DS.belongsTo('company'),
});
```

this way:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "company": {
            "uri": "<snip>/api/rest/company/5",
            "id": "5",
            "resource": "company"
        }
    }
]
```

while the default implementation for the RESTAdapter expects the server to respond like this:

```
[
    {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "company": "5"
    }
]
```

Comment: You might be able to use [EmbeddedRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html)

Comment: It's not really embedded data, just the Id in an object. instead of just the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ember Data 1.13, assuming you're fetching a single model, you'd override `normalizeFindRecordResponse` in your application serializer:

```
// serializers/application.js
normalizeFindRecordResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload) {

   var record = { id: payload.id, type: primaryModelClass.modelName };
   record.relationships = {};

   Object.keys(payload).forEach(function(key) {
     if (payload[key].id) { // it's an object with an id -> relationship
       record.relationships[key] = { data: { id: payload[key].id, type: key } };
     } else { // it's an attribute
       record.attributes[key] = payload[key];
     }
   })

   return { data: record };

}
```

That's the way forward for Ember Data 2.0: to massage your incoming server data to fit [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org).

Comment: Okay, but this way I have to manually correct all my relationships (in this example I have just one, but there are plenty more), the problem is that my rest api responds the same way for all relationships, I would like to to it  in a generic way, for every BelongsTo relationship

Comment: Make it the application serializer and use the arguments provided to make it generic?

Comment: aces, i'll try it out later this week and mark your answer as correct if it works, but firstly I need to take a look at the new serializer functions as the current extractHooks are deprecated.

Comment: @emberigniter, do you have a resource documenting the move to JSON-API? RFC maybe? I can't find it and am genuinely interested.

Comment: @xavier.cambar not really documenting the move, but i wrote about serializer/adapters for the latest ember data http://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/

Comment: @emberigniter Very good resource. I'd recommend it to anyone interested, really.